# Create VPC button not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I want to create amazon VPC but its not allowing me to create. The **Create VPC** button is not taking me anywhere.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Can I start my VPC wizard after this ?

[image: VPC screen]

Comment: Have you tried clicking in the button? If so, what happen? I see it enabled

Comment: Yes i clicked but its not taking me anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web page has not fully loaded. Try rebooting your computer or using a different browser.

The screen should look like:

[image: Create VPC]

Comment: It appears that you are having major networking issues on that computer, which is why it is unable to display information. It does not appear to be related to permissions because that would display a different error. Try rebooting and/or try using a different web browser. Try it on a different network (eg at home or at work). You are certainly not being presented with the correct screen content.

Comment: I have the same problem, tried with different browsers but still not working. I click on Create VPC and nothing happens. I only miss the Service endpoints section. Any idea?